# Resistor for indicator LED on higher voltage (70V) DC

Tags: led, resistors

I'm driving an N-channel MOSFET on a 70Vdc supply (to power a pinball machine's solenoid), and I want to add an indicator LED to the circuit *after* the MOSFET, to see whether the MOSFET responds as expected.

From my calculations I found that if I use a low-current LED (such as [this](https://www.conrad.nl/nl/vishay-tllg-5400-led-bedraad-groen-rond-5-mm-12-mcd-25-2-ma-19-v-186929.html) green 5mm LED at 2mA 1.9V) I should be able to do it with a 70Vdc supply voltage.

For the resistor I calculated:

\$ R = (V_{in} - V_{LED}) / I \$

\$ (70V - 1.9V) / 0.002A = 34k\Omega \$

And then the resistor would dissipate:

\$ P = (V_{in} - V_{LED}) \times I \$

\$ (70V - 1.9V) \times 0.002A = 0.14W \$

This seems reasonable, and any 1/4W resistor should do the job.

However, all online LED calculators that I could find tell me they they don't do LEDs with a supply voltage higher than approximately 35V. Are my calculations correct? Is there a better way to have an indicator LED on a 70Vdc supply?

Comment: Your numbers are right. However, you do need to protect the LED from reverse transients when the coil drive is released. Just do something like put a 1N4148 across the LED with the polarity reversed.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Indeed, I have a simple 1N4007 across there. What's the difference with an 1N4148?

Comment: https://www.conrad.nl/nl/broadcom-hlmp-hm65-y30dd-led-bedraad-groen-ovaal-38-x-52-mm-5040-mcd-40-100-20-ma-32-v-181203.html is about 500 x brighter at 2mA  , use 1n4148 and 33k is OK  and your link was RED LED and Groen is just a distributor like Digikey. For a brighter flash use down to 3.3k 2W or less depending on time duration.

Comment: Do you use an NMOS switch for each solenoid and want a separate indicator for each and every solenoid, when activated? (Just curious, as my pinball machine experience says there are lots of solenoids in there and not just one.)